# Sharepoint 2007 - Custom List provisioning - are List Forms needed at deployment?

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2007

I have a feature which is provisioning 1 document library and 2 custom lists. A folder is included for each list containing the schema.xml for that list. Each folder also contains the associated forms (AllItems, DispForm, EditForm, NewForm, etc.). Everything deploys/works correctly but it seems a little redundant having the same forms copied into each list's folder. There is nothing special about these lists - the are basically a default doc library/generic list with additional fields provided through new content types (derived from Item/Document).

As far as I can tell these forms are pretty generic. Are there pre-installed forms that I can reference from my list  so I don't have to deploy all of these extra files? Is there any reason I would not want to do this?

Update - moving xml in comment to original question for readability:

```
<Forms> 
    <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"/> 
    <Form Type="EditForm" Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"/> 
    <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main"/> 
    <Form Type="NewFormDialog" Path="EditDlg.htm">
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are virtual defaults that are used if you don't specify a concrete page.

All lists use these template defaults unless you use a tool like SharePoint designer to customize the page. Then the template is used to create the concrete page and you can customize the look for a particular list without affecting others.

For my custom definitions, I use

```
<List>
   ...
   <MetaData>
      ...
      <Forms>
         <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
         <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
         <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      </Forms>
   </MetaData>
</List>
```

If you have no reason to customize the out of the box version of these forms, you can use the virtual form and not deploy copies.

Comment: I'm not sure. A couple tools you can use to figure it out: go to your list and click New and view the URL. Go to an out-of-the-box list and do the same. Compare. If the root is the same and the only difference is the ListID GUID then you're probably using OOTB. You could also download SharePoint Manager (SPM) from CodePlex and examine your installation. Note that it must be run from the SharePoint server and lets you modify Object Model directly so can be dangerous if you start "playing" with things without knowing what it means. With SPM you can see information that may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Actually, looking more closely at the XML you included, it looks like you are referencing custom pages. If you edit your original question, you can add the XML at the bottom, highlight it and mark it as code so it'll be easier for people to play "spot the difference" and maybe answer the question better.

Comment: Thanks Erik that's all I need to know, I've moved the xml clip to the original question.